# What are the settings for receiving signals in MIMO mode with META information on BladeRF

Tags: c++, signal-processing, gnuradio, rtl-sdr

I need to receive signals on two channels RХ1 and RХ2 of the BladeRF device. At the same time, I want to receive metadata from the device. Unfortunately, all my attempts to receive a signal result in either an error or an overflow: Overrun detected on RX. 508 valid samples were read.

My C++ Windows application uses

- libbladeRF version: 2.4.1
- Firmware version: 2.4.0-git-a3d5c55f
- FPGA version: 0.14.0 (configured by USB host)

The code that starts receiving signals looks like this:

```
// test
// samples_per_buffer = 8192;
// num_buffers = 16;
// num_transfers = 8;
// stream_timeout_ms = 3000;
// frequency = 1700000000;
// samplerate = 2000000;
// bandwidth = 500000;

int status = bladerf_sync_config(dev_info.dev.lock().get(),
        BLADERF_RX_X2,                // using RX1 and RX2
        BLADERF_FORMAT_SC16_Q11_META, // META enabled
        num_buffers,
        samples_per_buffer,
        num_transfers,
        stream_timeout_ms);

status = bladerf_enable_module(dev_info.dev.lock().get(), BLADERF_RX, true);

memset(&meta, 0, sizeof(meta));
meta.flags = BLADERF_META_FLAG_RX_NOW;

while (is_receiving) {
        status = bladerf_sync_rx(device_it->dev.lock().get(), rx_buffer.data(), 262144, &meta, stream_timeout_ms);
}
```

Can you show me the working settings? But both channels RХ1 and RХ2 need to work, and metadata must also be received